# htaccess redirect all urls with question mark parameter to without

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, 301-redirect

I checked a lot, for my question. there are some close, but none that would solve my problem.

I need to permanently redirect ALL URLs that end in this:

```
?mode=list
```

AND

```
?mode=grid
```

to without (remove the question mark and what is after it)

Example:

```
example.com/random-url-here?mode=grid redirect to example.com/random-url-here
```

AND

```
example.com/whatever-url-here?mode=list redirect to example.com/random-url-here
```

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule (.*)$^mode=list $1
RewriteRule (.*)$^mode=grid $1
```

and this

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule (.*)$^mode=list $1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.*)$^mode=grid $1 [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work. Clearly, I don't understand how this works. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: The answer to your question is in the docs for [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). It's really better for me to direct you there rather than answer the question directly, because to manage Apache you'll need to read that whole page many times. You should also master regular expressions - there are many tutorials. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> example.com/random-url-here?mode=grid
> ```

The part of the URL after the first `?` (ie. `mode=grid` in this example) is called the *query string*.

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*)$^mode=list $1 [L,R=301]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` directive takes up to 3 arguments:

```
RewriteRule pattern substitution [flags]
```

The *pattern* (first argument) to the `RewriteRule` directive is a regular expression (regex) that matches against the requested **URL-path only**, which notably excludes the query string. Therefore you can't match the query string using the `RewriteRule` directive.

To match the query string you need to use an additional `RewriteCond` (condition) directive and check against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. `RewriteCond` directives apply *conditions* to the `RewriteRule` directive that follows.

However, the regex `(.*)$^mode=list` (apart from trying to match the query string) will *never* match in this context. `$` asserts the end-of-line and `^` asserts the start-of-line - so this will always fail.

In your example above, the `$1` backreference (in the *substitution string*) is attempting to match the URL-path. However, this URL-path (in a *directory* context, ie. `.htaccess`) does not start with a slash (ie. it's *relative*), so will result in a malformed redirect unless you also have a `RewriteBase` directive defined elsewhere in your `.htaccess` file. A *relative* substitution string is seen as a filesystem path relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

If you omit the `R` (`redirect`) flag in this context (as in your first example) then it will try to internally rewrite the request (not externally redirect), so the visible URL will not change.

Try the following instead, near the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mode=(list|grid)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The above states... for all URLs `(.*)` that have a query string of `mode=list` or `mode=grid` (exactly) then redirect to the same URL-path and discard the query string (`QSD` - Query String Discard). The `QSD` is new to Apache 2.4 (which I assume you are using). If you omit the `QSD` flag then you will get a redirect loop (since the query string will be re-appended to the redirected URL).

Note that the above matches the query string *exactly* (as in your examples). If there are any other URL parameters in the query string or the case is different then it will fail to match.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change it to a 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - when you have confirmed that it works OK. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: wow, what a wonderful gift, and great explanations! thank you so much, this works. highly appreciated